# Float to binary conversion in C(ieee 754)

Tags: c, binary, precision, converters

I am trying to get the 0000's to left of the conversion but I have a bit of trouble.

For example if I ask for *float_number*:`5`

--> I get `101`

--> but Correct Answer is `01000000101000000000000000000000`

```
#include <stdio.h>

    union intFloat
{
    int i;
    float f;
};


unsigned show_bits(unsigned input)
{
    int checker = input;
    int i,counter;

    int size = (sizeof(input)*8)-1;
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc(size+2);
    for(i=size,counter=0; i>=0; i--,counter++) 
    {
        
        if ( checker == 0)
            return 0;

        
        if ( checker == 1 )
            return 1;

        return (input % 2) + 10 * show_bits(input / 2);
    }
}

int main() 
{
union intFloat data;

    printf("Enter an int for encoding: ");
    scanf("%d", &data.i);
    printf(" Number = %d ",show_bits(data.i));
    printf("\n");

    printf("Enter a float for encoding: ");
    scanf("%f", &data.f);
    //call show bits
    printf(" Number = %d ",show_bits(data.f));

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to source online answer but every code in C is differently structure. I am a novice in C but would like to get more familiar with the language.

Comment: You should read about float expression first. What you did seem like convert for integer variable only.

Comment: you should read about limits for integer types. You can not hold the bit pattern as integer value.

Comment: If you want to convert decimal to binary, *never* use an integer type for your output.  It doesn't make sense, and it unnecessarily limits the size of the number you can convert.  Any decimal-to-binary function should either (a) construct a *string* or (b) print the constructed binary number immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `show_bits` is a bit bizarre:

- Why the for? You return immediately.
- Why `malloc` and then immediately leak?
- Why is your implementation recursively multiplying?
- You don't have 32 digit precision with an unsigned

I changed the function to be:

```c
#include <limits.h>
void show_bits(unsigned u) {
    const unsigned unsigned_bits = sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT;
    printf("Number: ");
    // Iterate over bits starting at the MSB
    for (unsigned bit = 0; bit < unsigned_bits; bit++) {
        printf("%u", (u & (1 << (unsigned_bits - bit - 1)) ? 1 : 0));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Using bit operations directly.

Then, after you scan the float, you mistakenly access the `.f` member. This is the core step where the punning happens. If you just use `.f`, you get the float member, and it will be converted to the unsigned int `5` automatically by the language upon being passed to a function taking `unsigned`.

Instead, you need to be using `data.i`. Type punning with unions is based on the fact, that the underlying memory is the same. The float is written into the memory of `data`. Now, when we access that memory through `data.i`, we treat the float's bit presentation as if it were an (unsigned) int. Therefore:

```c
int main() {
    union {
        int i;
        float f;
    } data;

    printf("Enter an int for encoding: ");
    scanf("%d", &data.i);
    show_bits(data.i);

    printf("Enter a float for encoding: ");
    scanf("%f", &data.f);
    show_bits(data.i);
}
```

Now correctly outputs:

```
Enter an int for encoding: 5
Number: 00000000000000000000000000000101
Enter a float for encoding: 5
Number: 01000000101000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Too many magic numbers

Comment: @0___________ could you propose a concrete change? `show_bits` could be explained more in-depth, although imo the focus of this question is on the type punning, not the specific binary formatting algorithm. But constants used don't seem very cryptic to me. Assuming unsigned is 32 bit is fair for a simple example imo, shouldn't be too confusing? The only other two are 1 and 0, should I have `const unsigned ONE = 1;`?

Comment: In C you do not have to use magic numbers. Be more portable. Magic numbers are bad

Comment: @0___________so your point is to use `sizeof`? That's fair I guess, i just wrote 32 without thinking about it much

Comment: @0___________edited

Comment: @Mikdore Don't stress over this sort of thing *too* much.  Magic numbers are not, in fact, always bad.  Here's a nice essay: [*Best Practices vs Witch Hunts*](https://accu.org/journals/overload/23/125/ignatchenko_2066/).

Comment: types in sizeof are not good as well

Comment: `1 << (unsigned_bits - bit - 1)` will overflow because `1` is an `int`. It should be `1u`. Or, more simply, `(u & (1 << (unsigned_bits - bit - 1)) ? 1 : 0)` can be just `u >> unsigned_bits-bit-1 & 1`. The union should use `unsigned` as well, not `int`. There should be a test that `sizeof (float)` and `sizeof (unsigned)` are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Yuo need to access its binary representation.

```
int printfloatasbin(const float x)
{
    unsigned long long mask = 1ull << (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
    unsigned long long val;

    memcpy(&val, &x, sizeof(x));
    while(mask)
    {
        printf("%d",!!(val & mask));
        mask >>= 1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printfloatasbin(5.0f);
}
```